# Sending/Receiving SOAP Requests/Responses in C

Tags: c, http, soap, tcp

I need a toolkit to implement SOAP requests and responses in a C production application. I've looked into gSOAP (no support), Apache Axis (not fully implemented according to their site). Has anyone been able to implement SOAP responses/requests over HTTP or TCP/IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a lower level approach (i.e. parse the XML response your self), you could invoke an application such as cURL (or invoke libcurl directly).  I have had very good fortune with this approach.

I have written programs that invoke cURL from the command line as follows:

```
  command_line << "--insecure"
               << " -d @" << request->post_file_name
               << " -H \"Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf8\""
               << " --output " << request->results_file_name
               << " --trace-time --trace-ascii " << curl_log_path
               << " " << fs_service_url;
```

Comment: I'm currently looking into this approach to solving the problem. The issue I've come up with is how to perform the HTTP POST to the SOAP service. I haven't found a way to send the whole XML file visa libcurl. Or do I have to send the POST as a string that has been read from the file?

Comment: I just edited my response to specify how curl can be invoked from the command line.  You would have to find the equivalent options when invoking libcurl.

Answer (score 1):

Ever tried [libsoup](http://library.gnome.org/devel/libsoup/stable/)?

> The libsoup library contains an HTTP
>   implementation and a set of API for
>   constructing and consuming SOAP
>   messages. It also allows for secure
>   authentication, so you can use web
>   services to access private accounts
>   over a secure connection. Using
>   libsoup makes it easy to use web
>   services without manually parsing and
>   interpreting the messages sent through

This is their main page -> [libsoup](http://live.gnome.org/LibSoup)

Comment: I'm looking for something a little more system independent than libsoup. Since I'm not sure if the production environment will have access gnome libraries and I don't want to have to install them, I decided to go with libcurl. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Apache Axis?](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/c/)

Comment: Apache Axis's site says that it isn't fully implemented for straight C. So I'm gonna stay away from it.